# Anaconda: ValueError: Could not interpret optimizer identifier

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, anaconda, sgd

I try to run this code:

```py
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation
from keras.optimizers import SGD
```

and I get this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'SGD' from 'keras.optimizers' (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\keras\optimizers.py)
```

Earlier when I was trying to learn keras with python, I did not encounter this problem, but later I encountered other errors. After I updated all the plugins and reinstalled anaconda3, I encountered this problem.

I changed the code content by referring to the information I found, and there is no error afterwards.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD
```

But later I encountered the following error:

```
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=SGD(lr=0.1),
             metrics=['accuracy'])

ValueError: Could not interpret optimizer identifier: <tensorflow.python.keras.optimizer_v2.gradient_descent.SGD object at 0x0000023987198520>
```

Are the above 2 questions related to connectivity?
Where is the error of `from keras.optimizers import SGD`?
`model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=SGD(lr=0.1),metrics=['accuracy'])` How should I modify it?

Please know that the seniors helped to point out the problem and the solution, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use anything from `tf.keras` (e.g. **SGD**) you should consistently use everything from `tf.keras`. I.e. `tf.keras.models` and `tf.keras.layers`

This is the recommendation for TF2.
Please see: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/quickstart/beginner

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation, I know where I made a mistake!